# Devise not login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created new role - Admin, with Devise.

```
rails generate devise Admin
```

in routes:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { sessions: 'admin/sessions', registrations: 'admin/registrations' }
  devise_scope :admin do
    get '/admin', to: 'admin/admins#index'
  end
```

in controllers I have: 
Admin/sessions_controller.rb
Admin/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end

class Admin::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

In path: localhost:3000/admin/sign_in -  I have authorization form, when i click button 'Login', I don't have any error, bun not redirecting in other root pages, simply stay in path localhost:3000/admin/sign_in without some errors.

```
Started POST "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-19 20:41:12 +0600
Processing by Admins::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WyJosiI1ynmsdCai0Dve0Lg1bm2OpQ7usDsSDIS6M5mU8e0gMeoc3/McG32maYs/ro5hdhnJeyUP2bnr9MAE7w==", "admin"=>{"email"=>"raf@mail.ruh", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Admin Exists (27.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = 'raf@mail.ruh' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered admins/shared/_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered admins/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 521ms (Views: 78.3ms | ActiveRecord: 27.8ms)
```

I don't know why?

Comment: Post your logs when you click on login

Comment: did you restart your server?

Comment: I added logs to my post

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any actions in yours Adminc controllers?
If not add actions with super

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def new
   super
  end
  ...
end
```